# How does one create a 'static' in a Swift class extension?

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

In several places here, it has been suggested that using a computed property within an extension of `NSDate` might a good way to obtain a string version of a date via a `NSDateFormatter`, like so:

```
extension NSDate {
    public var UTC : String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

However, allocating a `NSDateFormatter` is expensive and it is suggested that they be created once and cached.  The above code creates the `NSDateFormatter` every time a date is formatted, and I'm wondering if there is a way to create the `NSDateFormatter` once inside the extension for reuse?

Obviously, I could create it just once outside the extension, but that seems to defeat the encapsulation that characterizes classes.

I am reminded of: https://xkcd.com/1179/ !!

Comment: Apple says at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html: "The following classes and functions are generally not thread-safe. In most cases, you can use these classes from any thread as long as you use them from only one thread at a time. ... NSDateFormatter ..."

Comment: Actually, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/ says about NSDateFormatter THREAD SAFETY:

(1) On iOS 7 and later NSDateFormatter is thread safe,

(2) On OS X v10.9 and later NSDateFormatter is thread safe so long as you are using the modern behavior in a 64-bit app,

and (3) On earlier versions of the operating system, or when using the legacy formatter behavior or running in 32-bit on OS X, NSDateFormatter is not thread safe and you therefore must not mutate a date formatter simultaneously from multiple threads.

Comment: Cool, thanks @ramsay-consulting. That's a relief.

Comment: Bonus points for the xkcd comic. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add static members to class extensions just the same as on classes. You need to prefix the class name to the static member name when you use it, e.g. `NSDate.dateFormatterUTC`, even if you’re using it in the same class.

This works:

```
extension NSDate {
    private static let dateFormatterUTC: NSDateFormatter = {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        return formatter
    }()

    public var UTC : String {
        return NSDate.dateFormatterUTC.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

It’s also not the worst thing in the world just to use a private constant:

```
private let dateFormatterUTC: NSDateFormatter = {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    return formatter
}()

extension NSDate {
    public var UTC : String {
        return dateFormatterUTC.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

This is not significantly worse than the static class member, because Swift’s `private` is *file-private*, not *type-private*. These two declarations of `dateFormatterUTC` have the same scope. Even in the first example, `NSDate.dateFormatterUTC` is accessible throughout the entire file it’s declared in.

I do agree that the static version is preferable, but for stylistic reasons only: I like the way it’s indented right next to the thing that uses it.

As [Gwendal wisely notes above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602923/how-does-one-create-a-static-in-a-swift-class-extension/33603246#comment54982651_33602923), this approach assumes `UTC` will only ever be called from one thread. Although `static let` and global `let` are both thread-safe in Swift, <strike>the `NSDateFormatter` class is not!</strike> Looks like [it’s threadsafe starting in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602923/how-does-one-create-a-static-in-a-swift-class-extension/33603246#comment55020759_33602923). Phew.

Still, always good to keep a thread safety warning next to any mention of singletons. If you do want to use a non-threadsafe helper object from multiple threads, consider either creating a new helper on every call, or using `NSThread.currentThread().threadDictionary` to create a per-thread instance. Be sure to do a little profiling to make sure you’re actually solving a performance problem before opting for the more complex thread-local option.

Comment: Wisdom abounds on StackOverflow!  And I am a big fan of "stylistic reasons" so I like the static version too.  Many thanks to Gwendal and Paul ..

Comment: Ramsay Consulting did add [above](#comment55020759_33602923) a more accurate link from Apple about NSDateFormatter thread-safety.

Comment: Good to know! Updated answer to reflect this.